# Windows batch file to find duplicates in a tree

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need a batch file ( Windows CMD is the interpreter, a .bat ) to do this type of task:

1) Search through a folder and its subfolders

2) Find files with the same filename and extension ( aka duplicates )

3) Check if they have the same size

4) If same name + same size, echo all the files except the first one ( practically I need to delete all except one copy )

Thanks for any type of help

This is only an initial script, just for check the files, in a folder and its subfolders, and their size:

```
@Echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set Dir=C:\NewFolder

For /r "%Dir%" %%i in (*) do (
Set FileName=%%~nxi
Set FullPath=%%i
Set Size=%%~zi
Echo "!FullPath!" - SIZE: !Size!
)
Echo.
Pause
```

Comment: Can you add some code you've tried? In addition, some information about (for example) your operating system or command interpreter would be useful for potential answerers

Comment: Well the code i have write has some problem after the loop, i don't think the operative system make some difference for a .bat / CMD but is Windows XP

Comment: Try looking at this: http://superuser.com/questions/366487/make-a-batch-file-find-duplicate-file-names-with-different-extensions-and-actio I've not tried writing script/batch files for Windows but it seems like at least some success was had by the question asker in that case. In particular, take a look at `forfiles`, which is (according to Wikipedia) available from Win Vista onwards: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forfiles

Comment: forfiles /s /p <myPathWithoutBracketsHere> /c "echo @relpath" will give a list of all files by relative path, for example

Comment: I have Xp and i don't have forfiles, it's not a problem to get the filepath ( like `FOR /R "MYDIR" %%i IN (*) DO ECHO %%i` ) but is to check the duplicate, the file size and comparing all the information

Comment: `do echo %%~nzi` as the end of your command will give you the file size in bytes followed by the name. If you want a path before it as well, use `%%@fzi`

Comment: Incidentally, you can use `forfiles` with a 'Windows resource kit', apparently. See http://ss64.com/links/windows.html#kits, from http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html

Comment: Ok, i have added an example just for search the files. The problem is still there, point 2) 3) and 4)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This script does what you ask. Just set the ROOT variable at the top to point to the root of your tree.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set root="c:\test"
set "prevTest=none"
set "prevFile=none"
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%A in (
  '"(for /r "%root%" %%F in (*) do @echo %%~znxF:%%~fF:)|sort"'
) do (
  set "currTest=%%A"
  set "currFile=%%B:%%C"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  if !currTest! equ !prevTest! echo "!currFile!"
  endlocal
  set "prevTest=%%A"
)
```

But you can make the test more precise by using FC to compare the contents of the files. Also, you can incorporate the DEL command directly in the script. The script below prints out the commands that would delete the duplicate files. Remove the ECHO before the DEL command when you are ready to actually delete the files.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set root="c:\test"

set "prevTest=none"
set "prevFile=none"
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%A in (
  '"(for /r "%root%" %%F in (*) do @echo %%~znxF:%%~fF:)|sort"'
) do (
  set "currTest=%%A"
  set "currFile=%%B:%%C"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "match="
  if !currTest! equ !prevTest! fc /b "!prevFile!" "!currFile!" >nul && set match=1
  if defined match (
    echo del "!currFile!"
    endlocal
  ) else (
    endlocal
    set "prevTest=%%A"
    set "prevFile=%%B:%%C"
  )
)
```

Both sets of code may seem overly complicated, but it is only because I have structured the code to be robust and avoid problems that can plague simple solutions. For example, `!` in file names can cause problems with FOR variables if delayed expansion is enabled, and `=` in file name causes a problem with npocmoka's solution.

Comment: On Windows 10, by using a (example) root path with spaces like set root="c:\test path" with quotes in the variable I ended up with this error (note no quotes in front, two double quotes at end): path"" was unexpected at this time.
The script as written is double-quoting things twice.  The solution was to remove the quotes when defining the variable.

Comment: What would you need to remove here to find duplicates that don't necessarily have the same filename? So I assume the fastest way would be to check size and do fc on files with same size.

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off

setlocal 

for /f "tokens=1 delims==" %%# in ('set _') do (
    set "%%#="
)

for /r %%a in (*.*) do (
    if not defined _%%~nxa%%~za (
        set "_%%~nxa%%~za=%%~fa"
    ) else (
        echo %%~fa
    )
)

endlocal
```

Comment: +1, This will fail if a file name contains the `=` character. But otherwise, it is a good and simple algorithm.

Comment: Why the delayed expansion when you don't use it? It will cause problems if name contains `!`. Your algorithm doesn't need delayed expansion.

Comment: @dbenham I think `if not defined` will fail without delayed expansion. Didn't test it without it , but I have a such memory.

Comment: No, IF DEFINED does not need delayed expansion - that is one of the reasons I like it :-)  You also have a bug - your variable name needs to include the extension.

Comment: You also have a bug - your variable name needs to include the extension.

Comment: One last thing ;-)  You probably should add a prefix to each variable name, and clear all variables that begin with the prefix at the beginning. You don't want a false result because of any already existing variables.

Comment: @dbenham - added .Such case would never have occurred to me :-)